# Wordpress: Incomplete URL redirects to actual page

Tags: wordpress, redirect

Strange behavior for a Wordpress site. When I enter an incomplete URL, instead of getting a 404, I'm getting redirected to a page whose URL starts with the incomplete entry.

For example, when I enter this in my browser:

http://www.launchmoxie.com/jv/timeless

I'm redirected to:

http://www.launchmoxie.com/jv/timelessrhythm/timeless-rhythm-optin-confirmation/

There are several pages that begin with the initial URL, but I'd prefer that the user be given a 404, or I'd be okay with being able to set which of the pages gets served.

This behavior occurs for other pages with similar structures.

I'm pretty mystified. Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: This may be better asked on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com. In fact, [there's already a question and an answer about it there](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/92103/disable-wordpress-url-auto-complete). It appears it's default WP behaviour. (I'd never noticed before, but my site does the same thing.)

Comment: Thanks, Matt! Bizarre, that being default behavior, huh?

Comment: UPDATE: h/t to Matt Gipson, this is acknowledged behavior, and is being considered here: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16557

Comment: I'll put that as an answer here. I checked meta, at it seems that it's [not unreasonable to have the same question on different sites](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262292/how-do-i-handle-duplicates-when-they-are-asked-on-other-se-sites) in the network, as long as it seems appropriate for both.

Answer (score 1):

This is standard WordPress behaviour, and is part of the URL canonicalisation process—it's in [redirect_canonical](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/redirect_canonical). There's a [ticket to make just this auto-completion bit override-able](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16557), but it's not made it into a release yet.

In the meantime, there's a workaround suggested in that ticket:

```
function remove_redirect_guess_404_permalink( $redirect_url ) {
    if ( is_404() )
        return false;
    return $redirect_url;
}
add_filter( 'redirect_canonical', 'remove_redirect_guess_404_permalink' );
```

...which a helpful soul has also made [into a plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-url-autocorrect-guessing/).